# In a count model, how do I predict the change in y if one of my independent variables changes?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, stata, count-data, marginal-effect

I am using a count model--a negative binomial regression.

My dependent variable is count data (number of individual customers at each company in the industry).  Since at most companies there are no customers, and a small number of companies account for most customers, I need to use a count model like negative binomial.

My independent variables include company characteristics (NOT individual customer characteristics) and sales and marketing efforts targeted at those companies. Relatively few of the companies in the industry currently supply any customers, and relatively few are currently targeted for any marketing efforts (around 200 out of 2,000 are marketed to and around 200 supply customers).

I am trying to estimate how many more customers would likely materialize at each company (each observation) if sales and marketing efforts were increased at that company.  I have a single numerical variable that represents sales/marketing efforts and can range from zero to 4.

So if marketing went from zero to 4 or from 2 to 4, how many more customers would materialize at that company?

My negative binomial regression converges and gives plausible coefficients.  But I don't want marginal effects at the mean, or predicted values at current levels of sales and marketing.

I want the *difference* in predicted values for each observation if only one of my independent variables changed and everything else remained constant.

I'm using Stata, so please suggest answers accordingly.